# React Material OutlinedInput is notched if label not provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textbox

I have an issue with `OutlinedInput` wherein the textbox appears notched if I don't give the label. I want an outlined input textbox without any labels. This is my code:

```js
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '50ch' }} variant="outlined">
  <OutlinedInput
    id="old-password"
    type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
    value={values.password}
    onChange={handleChange('password')}
    endAdornment={
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton
          aria-label="toggle password visibility"
          onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
          edge="end"
        >
          {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    }
  />
</FormControl>
```

According to the official examples, the box should look like this:

[image: Not Focused]
[image: Focused]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try `notched={false}` for your `OutlinedInput`?

Comment: @ozgurkececioglu Yes already. Didn't work.

Comment: could you recreate the issue in codesandbox?. I didnt find any issue when used your code in codesandbox. check your dev tools. what data is getting in that span field. I have also checked adding label and then adding notched={false} as suggested by @ozgurkececioglu and it works fine.